# Create a batch file to run an msiexec in silent mode

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

I am trying to create a simple batchfile that will install a program, in this case InDesign. I have the command I need to us:

msiexec.exe /I "c:\Adobe InDesign CS6 x64\Build\InDesign.msi" \quiet

It has to be installed in quiet mode, that's the way it was made. I tried a real basic thing:

start cmd /c msiexec /I "c:\Adobe InDesign CS6 x64\Build\InDesign.msi" \quiet

But it didn't do anything. Ideally I'd like to have it create a log file and put it on the desktop. Any ideas?

Comment: Here are some tips for Adobe InDesign CS5: https://www.itninja.com/software/adobe/indesign-cs5/5-1637 - this is from ITNinja's list of "Software Tips" - notes on third party package installations.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong slash on quiet and I don't think you need to start a new window.
Try this:

```
msiexec /I "c:\Adobe InDesign CS6 x64\Build\InDesign.msi" /quiet
```

Initially you may want to leave off the /quiet so you can see what is going on if you are having trouble or use:

```
msiexec /I "c:\Adobe InDesign CS6 x64\Build\InDesign.msi" /passive
```

See MSIEXEC /? for help with logging.